# Uniqueness problem for an elliptic system

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, uniqueness-theorems

I want to prove the uniqueness of the solution of the following problem:
$$\eqalign{
  &  - d\,\Delta u + u = {u^p} \text{ in } \Omega   \cr 
  & u > 0 \text{ in } \Omega   \cr 
  & \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} = 0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega  \cr} $$
with $\Omega$ is a bounded open in $R^n$, $d>0$ and $p>1$.
I tried the classical methods but without any success. Thanx.

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason to expect uniqueness. On the contrary: $u=1$ is a trivial solution. Standard bifurcation theory shows that nontrivial solutions bifurcate when $(1-p)/d$ is an eigenvalue of the Neumann Laplacian.

Comment: Thank you sir. What if ${1-p}/d$ is not an eigenvalue of the Neumann laplacian, can we prove the uniqueness?. Cordially.

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate nonuniqueness for $n = 1$ via simple phase plane analysis, consider the system of ODEs
$$
\begin{cases}
u'(x) = v(x) \\
v'(x) = u(x) - (u(x))^p
\end{cases}
$$
with the initial conditions
$$
\begin{cases}
u(0) = a \\
v(0) = 0,
\end{cases}
$$
where $a$ is taken to belong to $(0, 1)$. The $v$-coordinate of the solution of the above IVP increases as long as its $u$-coordinate remains in $(0,1)$. After that, the $v$-coordinate decreases, and reaches $0$ at some finite $ A > 0$.  For $x \in [0, A]$ the $u$-coordinate keeps increasing. We have thus obtained a nontrivial positive solution of the elliptic BVP
$$
\begin{cases}
-u''(x) + u(x) - (u(x))^p = 0 & \text{ on } (0, A) \\
u'(0) = u'(A) = 0.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: try googling Lin-Ni Conjecture... I think this might be related...

Comment: But is there any conditions on p and q to expect uniqueness?

Comment: It appears that, in the one-dimensional case (on $[0,A]$), the existence of a nontrivial solution is equivalent to the existence of a solution of $v'=u$, $v'=\frac{1}{d}(u-u^p)$ starting at the positive $u$-semiaxis and reaching the semiaxis for $x=A$. The system of ODEs is a [Hamiltonian system](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Hamiltonian_systems), with $$H(u, v)=\frac{v^2}{2}-\frac{u^2}{2d} +\frac{u^{p+1}}{(p+1)d}.$$  And quite a lot is known on Hamiltonian systems (but I am no expert). To sum up, the problem boils down to that of (non)existence of periodic solutions of period $2A$.